# D3js can't find a node even though it's in the data

Tags: d3.js

The force simulation I'm trying to make has edges between nodes. In order for d3 to simulate the position of everything, those edges should have a .source and .target. I specified those sources and targets using strings, instead of the way that you see in most tutorials with the index of that item in the list of nodes.

The way this works is described here by Mike Bostock himself:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/533daf20348023dfdd76

But D3 can't find the nodes, if you look at my jsfiddle it already fails when trying to link the first edge in the edge-list. What am I doing wrong? All thoughts appreciated! I don't really know how to debug this myself as the mapping occurs behind the scenes of d3js.

Link to a sort of minimum example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wouterwouter/q2zec0no/1/

```
var data = {
  "edges": [{
    "index": 0,
    "keggreactionid": "R05300",
    "source": "C04559",
    "target": "C04112",
    "hits": "01416-1_AHCVY7AFXX_S",
    "enzymename": "muconate cycloisomerase;\nmuconate cycloisomerase I;\ncis,cis-muconate-lactonizing enzyme;\ncis,cis-muconate cycloisomerase;\nmuconate lactonizing enzyme;\n4-carboxymethyl-4-hydroxyisocrotonolactone lyase (decyclizing);\nCatB;\nMCI;\n2,5-dihydro-5-oxofuran-2-acetate lyase (decyclizing);\n2,5-dihydro-5-oxofuran-2-acetate lyase (ring-opening)\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 1,
    "keggreactionid": "R05299",
    "source": "C06730",
    "target": "C04112",
    "hits": "01416-1_AHCVY7AFXX_S",
    "enzymename": "catechol 1,2-dioxygenase;\ncatechol-oxygen 1,2-oxidoreductase;\n1,2-pyrocatechase;\ncatechase;\ncatechol 1,2-oxygenase;\ncatechol dioxygenase;\npyrocatechase;\npyrocatechol 1,2-dioxygenase;\nCD I;\nCD II\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 2,
    "keggreactionid": "R05299",
    "source": "C00007",
    "target": "C04112",
    "hits": "01416-1_AHCVY7AFXX_S",
    "enzymename": "catechol 1,2-dioxygenase;\ncatechol-oxygen 1,2-oxidoreductase;\n1,2-pyrocatechase;\ncatechase;\ncatechol 1,2-oxygenase;\ncatechol dioxygenase;\npyrocatechase;\npyrocatechol 1,2-dioxygenase;\nCD I;\nCD II\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 3,
    "keggreactionid": "R05865",
    "source": "C06760",
    "target": "C00058",
    "hits": "15416-7_AHCVY7AFXX_S",
    "enzymename": "2-hydroxymuconate-6-semialdehyde hydrolase;\n2-hydroxy-6-oxohepta-2,4-dienoate hydrolase;\n2-hydroxymuconic semialdehyde hydrolase;\nHMSH;\nHOD hydrolase;\nxylF (gene name);\n2-hydroxymuconate-semialdehyde formylhydrolase;\n2-hydroxymuconate-semialdehyde hydrolase\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 4,
    "keggreactionid": "R05865",
    "source": "C06760",
    "target": "C11354",
    "hits": "15416-7_AHCVY7AFXX_S",
    "enzymename": "2-hydroxymuconate-6-semialdehyde hydrolase;\n2-hydroxy-6-oxohepta-2,4-dienoate hydrolase;\n2-hydroxymuconic semialdehyde hydrolase;\nHMSH;\nHOD hydrolase;\nxylF (gene name);\n2-hydroxymuconate-semialdehyde formylhydrolase;\n2-hydroxymuconate-semialdehyde hydrolase\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 5,
    "keggreactionid": "R05865",
    "source": "C00001",
    "target": "C00058",
    "hits": "15416-7_AHCVY7AFXX_S",
    "enzymename": "2-hydroxymuconate-6-semialdehyde hydrolase;\n2-hydroxy-6-oxohepta-2,4-dienoate hydrolase;\n2-hydroxymuconic semialdehyde hydrolase;\nHMSH;\nHOD hydrolase;\nxylF (gene name);\n2-hydroxymuconate-semialdehyde formylhydrolase;\n2-hydroxymuconate-semialdehyde hydrolase\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 6,
    "keggreactionid": "R05865",
    "source": "C00001",
    "target": "C11354",
    "hits": "15416-7_AHCVY7AFXX_S",
    "enzymename": "2-hydroxymuconate-6-semialdehyde hydrolase;\n2-hydroxy-6-oxohepta-2,4-dienoate hydrolase;\n2-hydroxymuconic semialdehyde hydrolase;\nHMSH;\nHOD hydrolase;\nxylF (gene name);\n2-hydroxymuconate-semialdehyde formylhydrolase;\n2-hydroxymuconate-semialdehyde hydrolase\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 7,
    "keggreactionid": "R05864",
    "source": "C11354",
    "target": "C06762",
    "hits": "unbinned 15416-4_AHC",
    "enzymename": "2-hydroxyhexa-2,4-dienoate hydratase;\ntesE (gene name);\nhsaE (gene name)\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 8,
    "keggreactionid": "R05864",
    "source": "C00001",
    "target": "C06762",
    "hits": "unbinned 15416-4_AHC",
    "enzymename": "2-hydroxyhexa-2,4-dienoate hydratase;\ntesE (gene name);\nhsaE (gene name)\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 9,
    "keggreactionid": "R00750",
    "source": "C00084",
    "target": "C03589",
    "hits": "22316-6_AHCVY7AFXX_S",
    "enzymename": "4-hydroxy-2-oxovalerate aldolase;\n4-hydroxy-2-ketovalerate aldolase;\nHOA;\nDmpG;\n4-hydroxy-2-oxovalerate pyruvate-lyase;\n4-hydroxy-2-oxopentanoate pyruvate-lyase;\nBphI;\n4-hydroxy-2-oxopentanoate pyruvate-lyase (acetaldehyde-forming)\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }, {
    "index": 10,
    "keggreactionid": "R00750",
    "source": "C00022",
    "target": "C03589",
    "hits": "22316-6_AHCVY7AFXX_S",
    "enzymename": "4-hydroxy-2-oxovalerate aldolase;\n4-hydroxy-2-ketovalerate aldolase;\nHOA;\nDmpG;\n4-hydroxy-2-oxovalerate pyruvate-lyase;\n4-hydroxy-2-oxopentanoate pyruvate-lyase;\nBphI;\n4-hydroxy-2-oxopentanoate pyruvate-lyase (acetaldehyde-forming)\n",
    "root": null,
    "color": null
  }],
  "nodes": [{
    "compoundid": "C04559",
    "compoundname": "C04559",
    "id": "C04559"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C04112",
    "compoundname": "C04112",
    "id": "C04112"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C06730",
    "compoundname": "C06730",
    "id": "C06730"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C00007",
    "compoundname": "C00007",
    "id": "C00007"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C06760",
    "compoundname": "C06760",
    "id": "C06760"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C00001",
    "compoundname": "C00001",
    "id": "C00001"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C00058",
    "compoundname": "C00058",
    "id": "C00058"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C11354",
    "compoundname": "C11354",
    "id": "C11354"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C06762",
    "compoundname": "C06762",
    "id": "C06762"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C00084",
    "compoundname": "C00084",
    "id": "C00084"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C00022",
    "compoundname": "C00022",
    "id": "C00022"
  }, {
    "compoundid": "C03589",
    "compoundname": "C03589",
    "id": "C03589"
  }]
}


//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var w = 500;
var h = 500;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data['nodes'])
  .force('link', d3.forceLink(data.edges))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2));



var nodesgroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr('class', 'nodes')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(data['nodes'])
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 5);

//Create edges as lines
var edgesgroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr('class', 'edges')
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(data['edges'])
  .enter()
  .append("line");


simulation.on("tick", function() {

  edgesgroup
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr('strokeyness', 5)

  .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  nodesgroup.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

});


console.log('script has run.');
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: missing: C04559
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the [id of your nodes](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_id) if it is not `index`.

So you need :

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data['nodes'])
  .force('link', d3.forceLink(data.edges).id(function(n) {return n.id; }))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2));
```